# How to make sensors-detect work on my Intel Pentium M, thus stopping the fan?

Tags: drivers, cpu, dell-latitude, kernel-module, lm-sensors

After successfully installing `lm-sensors` on my fresh *Turnkey Linux* I called `sensors-detect`. Alas, it reports **it can not detect any sensors**. I did try the 2010 script that comes with my Turnkey distro, also I downloaded the current one.

I run a linux kernel 2.6.32-5-686 on a good old *Dell D400 Latitude* -- an "Intel Pentium M 1.8GHz" inside (family 6, model 13, stepping 6), as told by `/proc/cpuinfo`. I [gather](http://lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices) that `coretemp` would be the driver of choice.

It seems the key point is that the kernel module `coretemp` does not fint and devices. If I run `modprobe coretemp` it says

```
FATAL: error inserting coretemp (.../coretemp.ko): No such device
```

What "device" is meant? Is this the correct driver?

I do get some at `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM/temperature`. <strike>But I suspect it to be fake, it always shows 46°C.</strike> *It currently shows values between 46°C and 47°C.*

Also `/proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/` contains information, this time it seems useful. For example `cat info`

```
processor id: 0
acpi id: 0
bus master control: yes
power management: yes
throttling control: yes
limit interface: yes
```

Doing an `echo 4 > throttling` (4=50%) actually does have the effect that the CPU seems to be running slower. I also tried `6` (25%) and 7 (12%). Alas, the **fan keeps humming** nonetheless.

Any idea how I can **silence down** this excellent piece of computer without ripping out the wires (which probably is not a good idea)?

---

**Update** `dmidecode` output

```
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.3 present.
61 structures occupying 2324 bytes.
Table at 0x000F8CF0.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Dell Computer Corporation
    Version: A08
    Release Date: 06/28/2005
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 512 kB
    Characteristics:
            ISA is supported
            PCI is supported
            PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
            PNP is supported
            APM is supported
            BIOS is upgradeable
            BIOS shadowing is allowed
            Boot from CD is supported
            Selectable boot is supported
            3.5"/720 KB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
            8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
            Serial services are supported (int 14h)
            Printer services are supported (int 17h)
            CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
            ACPI is supported
            USB legacy is supported
            AGP is supported
            Smart battery is supported
            BIOS boot specification is supported
            Function key-initiated network boot is supported

Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 25 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Computer Corporation
    Product Name: Latitude D400
    Version: Not Specified
...
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch

...

Handle 0x0400, DMI type 4, 32 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: Microprocessor
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Pentium M
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: D6 06 00 00 BF F9 E9 AF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 13, Stepping 6
    Flags:
            FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
            VME (Virtual mode extension)
            DE (Debugging extension)
            PSE (Page size extension)
            TSC (Time stamp counter)
            MSR (Model specific registers)
            MCE (Machine check exception)
            CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
            SEP (Fast system call)
            MTRR (Memory type range registers)
            PGE (Page global enable)
            MCA (Machine check architecture)
            CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
            PAT (Page attribute table)
            CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
            DS (Debug store)
            ACPI (ACPI supported)
            MMX (MMX technology supported)
            FXSR (Fast floating-point save and restore)
            SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
            SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
            SS (Self-snoop)
            TM (Thermal monitor supported)
            PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Not Specified
    Voltage: 3.3 V
    External Clock: 133 MHz
    Max Speed: 1800 MHz
    Current Speed: 1800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: None
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0700
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0701
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided

...

Handle 0x1B00, DMI type 27, 12 bytes
Cooling Device
    Type: Fan
    Status: OK
    OEM-specific Information: 0x0000DD00

Handle 0x1C00, DMI type 28, 20 bytes
Temperature Probe
    Description: CPU Internal Temperature
    Location: Processor
    Status: OK
    Maximum Value: 127.0 deg C
    Minimum Value 0.0 deg C
    Resolution: 1.000 deg C
    Tolerance: 0.5 deg C
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x0000DC00
```

**update** `sensors-detect` output:

```
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
Intel Core family thermal sensor...                         No
Intel Atom thermal sensor...                                No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

...
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no):
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor'...                   No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x1011
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor'...                   No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

...
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no):
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

...
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no):
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

...
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no):
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Sorry, no sensors were detected.
```

Comment: Wire ripping is certainly not a good idea. Do you have the latest [BIOS version A08](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails?driverId=R104377), dating from 7/13/2005 ? It also seems that Dell has only foreseen Windows for this computer, so that installing a new BIOS or finding good Linux drivers might be problematic. The problem might also be solved by an active laptop cooler.

Comment: Yes, A08 it is. I thought maybe the chipset was generic-ish, or the CPU, so drivers may work. You think the BIOS is in the way?

Comment: Your BIOS is apparently the latest available for this computer. I haven't been able to find out if S.M.A.R.T. is available on it, but you could maybe try and [use smartctl](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/using-smartctl-to-get-smart-status-information-on-your-hard-drives/1389) to get more info.

Comment: Can you provide your sensors-detect output? This usually is pretty helpful in guiding you to a appropriate kernel module. Usually you have to play games with your /etc/modprobe.conf to alias your hardware to a specific name so that the driver will match correctly.

Comment: @sim: Ok, I will when I get home. Until then it only says (out of my head) it detects "SMC" (?), probably tries something with that, then continues with further tests, asks me it it should _really_ continue... but everything is "No".

Comment: @harrymc: I double-checked: I had A06 running. I updated to A08, but the changes are minor so I did not expect anything from it. And indeed, no: Still no `sensors-detect` success.

Comment: Maybe you should try another Live Linux distribution like Ubuntu. If this doesn't work, then I assume that your computer's sensors are not (or were never) operational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with lm-sensors is that you have to figure out the correct kernel module to load for your specific hardware. Different motherboards use different I2C (I Squared C) chipsets so that's where most of the difficultly lies.

I would confirm your suspicion a little more about using coretemp by making sure that your MB is in fact the one you think it is. You can use dmidecode to interrogate it further like so:

```
% sudo dmidecode | less
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.6 present.
78 structures occupying 2867 bytes.
Table at 0x000E0010.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: LENOVO
        Version: 6IET74WW (1.34 )
        Release Date: 10/25/2010
        Address: 0xE0000
        Runtime Size: 128 kB
        ROM Size: 8192 kB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
                PNP is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                ESCD support is available
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.52
        Firmware Revision: 1.19
...
...
```

Comment: What of this output is the important line? I will execute it as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another Live Linux distribution like Ubuntu.

If this doesn't work, then I assume that your computer's sensors are not (or were never) operational.